# How can i get the minimum item more efficiently?

Tags: python, filter, min

I have a list consist of tuple items like `(id, cost, clicks, views)`  as below:

```
statistic_data_list = [(12324, 9, 6, 9), (12325, 11, 5, 3), (12326, 10, 7, 2)]
```

And I want to get the item's id which meet following conditions:

- 1 when not all `cost` of item is equal to 0, get the item's id which `cost` is lowest.
- 2 when all `cost` of item is equal 0, then if not all `clicks` of item is equal to 0, get the item's id which `clicks` is lowest.
- 3 when all `clicks` of item is equal to 0, then if not all `views` of item is equal to 0, get the item's id which `views` is lowest.

```
# (1)
#  input:  
[(12324, 9, 6, 9), (12325, 11, 5, 3), (12326, 10, 7, 2)]
#  expected result: 
12324 # (whose cost is lowest) 

# (2)
#  input:  
[(12324, 0, 6, 9), (12325, 0, 5, 3), (12326, 0, 7, 2)]
#  expected result:
12325 #  (whose clicks is lowest when all cost is 0)

# (3)
#  input:  
[(12324, 0, 0, 9), (12325, 0, 0, 3), (12326, 0, 0, 2)]
#  expected result: 
12326  #  (whose views is lowest when all cost is 0 also clicks)
```

How can I get the specified item's id more efficiently?

```
# My attemp so far

cost_clicks_views_list = [(12324, 9, 6, 9), (12325, 11, 5, 3), (12326, 10, 7, 2)]

len_cost_not_0 = len(list(filter(lambda item: item[1], cost_clicks_views_list)))
len_clicks_not_0 = len(list(filter(lambda item: item[2], cost_clicks_views_list)))
len_views_not_0 = len(list(filter(lambda item: item[3], cost_clicks_views_list)))


if len_cost_not_0:
    min_cost_id_list = [ item[0] for item in cost_clicks_views_list if item[1]==min([i[1] for i in cost_clicks_views_list]) ]
    print(min_cost_id_list) # [(12324]

else:
    if len_clicks_not_0:
        min_clicks_id_list = [item[0] for item in cost_clicks_views_list if item[2] == min([i[2] for i in cost_clicks_views_list])]
        print(min_clicks_id_list) # [(12325]

    else:
        if len_views_not_0:
            min_views_id_list = [item[0] for item in cost_clicks_views_list if item[3] == min([i[3] for i in cost_clicks_views_list])]
            print(min_views_id_list)  # [12326]
```

Any commentary is very welcome. great thanks.

Comment: (a) Your chances of getting a great answer would multiply if your sample data covers all the mentioned scenarios, and if you also mention the expected output for the sample data. Currently, I don't think your sample data covers all mentioned scenarios  (b) Your current attempt makes several passes over the list (I can count at least four passes. Each `len(filter())`operation is one pass). My hunch is that you should  be able to solve it in one pass.

Comment: Your sample data shows fractional values for clicks

Comment: @fountainhead thx for your reply,  I've corrected my poor mistake of  fractional values for clicks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for checking these. When at least one `cost` among all items is not equal to zero, to get the item's `id` whose `cost` is lowest, try this :

```
sdl = [(12324, 10, 0.6, 9), (12325, 11, 0.5, 3), (12326, 10, 0.7, 2)]
a = [j[0] for j in sdl if j[1]==min([k[1] for k in sdl if all([True if i[1] != 0 else False for i in sdl])])]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
a = [12324, 12326]
```

Here all three items have non-zero `cost` and lowest cost is `10` corresponding to which there are two ids `12324` and `12326`.